# Remplazar el abecedario entero con numeros en Python

Tags: string, input

estoy haciendo ejercicios de python para aprender pero hay uno que aun con lo que se supone que aprendi hasta el momento deberia saber como hacerlo, pero mi cabeza no llega a procesar la forma que se tiene que hacer.

Quisiera que alguien me pueda decir simplemente que funcion usarian, ya que decirme el ejercicio no estaria aprendiendo

[image: Este es el ejercicio]

```
txt = input('Escribi una palabra: ').lower()

abecedario = ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','ñ','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z')

numeros = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,23,24,25,26,27)

for letra in abecedario:
    txt = txt.replace(letra, str(numeros))

print(txt)
```

Esto es lo que tenia escrito pero da como output lo largo en tuplas, ej palabra hola = 4 tuplas con todos los numeros

Comment: Si agregas el código que has intentado sería mas fácil para buscar la solución.

Comment: No logre escribir ninguno ya que con lo que llevo aprendido no entiendo como hacer algo asi, leei que se puede usar la funcion ord, pero todavia no llegue a eso asi que no tiene mucho sentido

Comment: En que lenguaje estás implementando o quieres implementar lasolución. Si no cuentas con código al menos puedes proporcionar un pseudocódigo, pero te animo a que lo intentes y después compartas en dónde tienes problemas. Recuerda que puedes editar la pregunta para agregar más detalles.

Comment: Si perdon por no añadir el lenguaje, es en python y esta bien voy a intentar escribir algo aunque realmente no tengo idea como hacerlo

Comment: @ricardo-dlc ahi añadi el intento que habia hecho pero creo que voy por el lado equivocado por eso queria saber que usaria alguien, sin contar la funcion ord que aun si busque en internet y eso me fue util todavia no la aprendi entonces queria hacer el ejercicio con lo que venia viendo hasta ahora